# Format Raw Hdd in int 13

Tags: assembly, x86, filesystems, nasm

I want to change file system of hard disk drive using assembly.
I have found fixed disk format track in http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-13.htm but I could not 
understand.

```
;not succesful
mov ax,0
mov es,ax
mov ah,05h
mov al,08h
mov ch,01h
mov dh,00h
mov dl,80h
mov bx,type
int 13h
cmp ah,00
jne error
suc:
ret
error:
hlt
type:
dw 00,00,08,03
```

I have tried this example in my os. It was going to halt when this function was called.

Comment: On quick inspection, you set `es` to `0` but `type` may not be in data segment `0`. Your `type` buffer is 8 bytes, but the documentation for `int 13h` says you need a 512-byte buffer. There may be other issues as well...

Comment: okey but i tried this

Comment: type times 512 dw 00,00,08,03?

Comment: Changing the filesystem on a hard drive only involves writing the necessary byte structures to the disk - it does not involve low-level formatting.

Comment: Drew if you are right what have i must done?

Comment: I assume you expect to use the drive after changing its type. It will therefore need to be formatted. Changing it's type doesn't format. If you're going to format the whole drive, wouldn't you want `int 13h` and `ah = 07h` (http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0618.htm)?

Comment: Sorry mbratch i cannot understood somethings because of my poor english .that so can you give example about int 13h func 7?

Comment: It's in the link that I gave. That link points to the function which formats the whole drive.

Comment: I was Tried This ,That was not worked.I think i must use ports?Isn't not?